# Emacs evil-mode: how to make visual selection to include diacritics?

Tags: evil

For a text "naïve", for example, and the cursor is at "n", if I press `vll`, "naï" is highlighted, but if I press `y`, the yanked text is "nai", not "naï".

How to make visual selection to include all diacritics/combining characters at the selection ending?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the issue on my machine.  May be a bug, or may simply be a product of encodings.

It appears to be the case that your "naïve" (as transmitted to me through `elfeed`) uses a regular "i" with some sort of visual diacritics rather than the unicode "ï".  You can tell by putting the cursor on your "ï" and running `M-x what-cursor-position`, which should return something like:

```
Char: i (105, #o151, #x69) point=321 of 343 (93%) column=1
```

Here's what you get with "naïve" when you use the *unicode* "ï":

```
Char: ï (239, #o357, #xef, file #xC3 #xAF) point=446 of 449 (99%) column=61
```

If you use unicode, `evil` will realize that you're talking about a single character.  So: unicode encoding and entry in probably the most effective way to fix the problem.

The practical step if you can't do that is to move one more point over.  So, for example, `vll` visually highlights "naï" but yanking only gets you "nai".  `vlll` visually highlights "naïv" and yanking gets you "naï".

(Note that I've mixed-and-matched the unicode "ï" in here so that the visuals will show up.)

Comment: The correct term for these is "Combining characters".

Comment: In some languages, there is no Unicode characters to represent each combination, for example, ကြီး (= က+ြ+ီ+း) in Burmese. Adding more `l`s to move cursor is hard when there is multiple combining characters, because there is no visual indication to indicate "current" combining character.

Comment: Could you please post your issue in Evil issues tracker?
https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues?status=new&status=open